# Is the permits relationship of Java Sealed classes/interfaces transitive

Tags: java, java-17, sealed, sealed-class

If I read the JLS [§8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) and [§9.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.4) correctly, the classes that a sealed class/interface permits, are just the *direct* subclasses/interfaces.

To illustrate this, consider the following example:

```java
public sealed interface I1 permits I2, C, D { /*...*/ }
public final class C implements I1 { /*...*/ }
public final class D implements I1 { /*...*/ }

public sealed interface I2 extends I1 permits E, F { /*...*/ }
public final class E implements I2 { /*...*/ }
public final class F implements I2 { /*...*/ }
```

If I understand the specification correctly, `I1` obviously permits `C` and `D` but not `E` and `F` (via the `extends` hierarchy of `I2` from `I1`). Is this correct?

The reason I'm asking is what patterns are allowed for switch expressions of the following kind:

```java
I1 i1 = // ...
return switch (i1) {
    case C c -> "1";
    case D d -> "2";
    case E e -> "3"; // Can we match over E?
    case F f -> "4"; // Can we match over F?
    default  -> "5";
};
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're asking why does the switch work, when `I1` doesn't directly permit `E` and `F`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, that's the question. If `I1` doesn't directly permit `E` and `F` but they are possible as a pattern of the `switch` expression then I would say that *permit* is a transitive relationship because they are included in the set of patterns.

Comment: Okay, I think I've adequately answered why the switch works then. The JLS specifies things in a different way than you expected, it seems :)

Comment: The `permits` clause of a class declaration lists the classes that are allowed to directly extend this one (just as the `extends` and `implement` clauses list only the ones that are directly extended).  This is not an exhaustive list of possible subclasses, because a permitted subclass could have its own subclasses.

Comment: You've assumed "permits" means (or should mean) "permitted subtypes", when it really means "permitted direct subclasses."  There are multiple reasons why this assumption would be the wrong choice: (a) more burdensome for authors, (b) not all subtypes can be known (a permitted subclass can be non-sealed), (c) inconsistent with meaning of `extends`, (d) some subtype names may be non-denotable (e.g., lambdas, anonymous classes).  And probably more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `I1` obviously permits `C` and `D` but not `E` and `F`. Is this correct?

More accurately, you can say that `C` and `D` are in the set of *permitted direct subclasses* of `I1`, which is a term defined in section 9.1.4. The JLS doesn't really define what "`I1` *permits* `C` and `D`" means though.

As for your switch expression, the reason why it works is two-fold. First, you are able to write a type pattern in a switch label if the type of the switch selector expression is downcast-convertible to that type.

[14.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/preview/specs/patterns-switch-record-patterns-jls.html#jls-14.11.1)

> A pattern case element p is switch compatible with T if p is applicable at type T ([14.30.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/preview/specs/patterns-switch-record-patterns-jls.html#jls-14.30.3)).

14.30.3:

> A pattern p is said to be applicable at a type T if one of the following rules apply:
>
> - A type pattern that declares a pattern variable of a reference type U is applicable at another reference type T if T is downcast convertible to U ([5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/preview/specs/patterns-switch-record-patterns-jls.html#jls-5.5)).

Obviously, `E` is downcast-convertible to `I1` through a widening reference conversion, because `E` implements `I1`. Note that this fact has nothing to do with `permits`. It is simply a result of `E implements I2` and `I2 extends I1`. Surely you would agree that `implements` and `extends` are transitive!

Second, switch expressions need to be exhaustive. Your switch expression is always exhaustive because it has a `default` case. However, it is still exhaustive even without the `default` case.

From now on, we will consider your switch expression but without the `default` case, because that is where `permits` plays a role. The rules to determine whether the set of case labels you wrote are exhaustive are specified in [14.11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/preview/specs/patterns-switch-record-patterns-jls.html#jls-14.11.1.1). The important bit of your case is (this is kind of an inductive definition):

> - A set of case elements is exhaustive for a type T if it contains a pattern that is unconditional at type T (14.30.3).
> - A set of case elements is exhaustive for a type T that includes an abstract and sealed class or interface named C, if it is exhaustive
>   for every applicable permitted direct subtype of T.

"applicable permitted direct subtype of T" in your case is really just the same as "permitted direct subtype of T". You can also treat "a type T that includes an abstract and sealed class or interface named C" as the same as `T` - the "includes" relationship isn't relevant to your case. With `T=I1` in mind, we can start "running" this algorithm.

We use the second rule first - the permitted direct subtypes of `I1` are `I2`, `C` and `D`. Since we have a `C c` and `D d` in the case elements, we know that our set of case elements is exhaustive for `C` and `D` (first rule). Is it also exhaustive for `I2`? To determine that, we use the second rule again. The permitted direct subtypes of `I2` are `E` and `F`. Using the first rule, we know that the case elements `E e` and `F f` are exhaustive for `E` and `F` respectively. We have now proven that that the set of case elements are exhaustive for `I2`, `C` and `D`, so it is exhaustive for `I1`, according to the second rule.

So if you are talking about how switch patterns work, I think "inductive" is a better word to describe how the exhaustiveness of switch case labels are verified.

Comment: Since the OP’s example code has a `default` label, it’s always exhaustive.

Comment: @Holger (Facepalms) I had planned to put that in the answer, but then I anticipated the OP to ask “why is it still exhaustive when I remove the default branch?”, so I wrote the whole second half, but then forgetting to address the OP’s actual code!

Answer (score 1):

> If I read the JLS `§8.1.6` and `§9.1.4`, correctly the classes that a sealed class/interface permits, are just the **direct sub classes/interfaces**.

Each sealed class or interface needs to specify at least one **direct** permitted class (*or interface*). There's no need to specify non-directs subclasses, they are granted with the permission by default (*since they are allowed to extend their direct parent*).

Specification explicitly tells that **only direct** subclasses can be provided in the `permits` clause, [§8.1.6. Permitted Direct Subclasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6):

> Every permitted direct subclass specified by the permits clause **must
> be** a **direct subclass** of `C` (`§8.1.4`), or a **compile-time error occurs**.

Permitted classes should be necessarily marked with either of these modifiers: `sealed`, `non-sealed` and `final` (*the latter modifier for obvious reasons can't be used with interfaces*).

If a subclass is `final` it can't be extended.

By declaring a permitted subclass (*subinterface*) as `non-sealed` you're loosening the constraints. Such class is allowed to be extended as a regular class (*no* `permits` *clause required*).

If the subclass is being marked as `sealed` then the cycle repeats: it in turn has to have a `permite` clause specifying its direct subclasses.

Here's a quote from the [JEP 409: Sealed Classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/409):

> A sealed class imposes three constraints on its permitted subclasses:
>
> **1.** The sealed class and its permitted subclasses must belong to the same module, and, if declared in an unnamed module, to the same
> package.
>
> **2.** **Every permitted subclass must directly extend the sealed class.**
>
> **3.** Every permitted subclass must use a modifier to describe how it propagates the sealing initiated by its superclass:
>
> - A permitted subclass may be declared `final` to prevent its part of the class hierarchy from being extended further. (Record classes
>   are implicitly declared `final`.)
> - A permitted subclass may be declared `sealed` to allow its part of the hierarchy to be extended further than envisaged by its sealed
>   superclass, but in a restricted fashion.
> - A permitted subclass may be declared `non-sealed` so that its part of the hierarchy reverts to being open for extension by unknown
>   subclasses. A `sealed` class cannot prevent its permitted subclasses
>   from doing this.

That said, if you change the declaration of the sealed super interface `I1` by specifying non-direct subclasses `E` and `F` after `permits` clause it would **not** compile:

```
public sealed interface I1
       permits I2, C, D, E, F {
    /*...*/
}
```

And we restore the initial declaration of `I1` (by removing `E` and `F`) the following code would work fine

```
public static String foo(I1 i1) {
    
    return switch (i1) {
        case C c -> "1";
        case D d -> "2";
        case E e -> "3";
        case F f -> "4";
        default  -> "5";
    };
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(foo(new E()));
    System.out.println(foo(new F()));
}
```

*Output:*

```
3
4
```